# Integer property as automated generated number

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a simple Java app that would store and display information for customers.

I want to make the `id` as an automated generated number but having problems with that, don't know should I set it in get or set methods? 
Can anyone help me to use that value as?

Here is an example:

```
public class Customer{

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String address, String country){
    this.id.set(Integer.parseInt(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
    this.firstName.set(firstName);
    this.lastName.set(lastName);
    this.email.set(email);
    this.address.set(address);
    this.country.set(country);
}

private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this,"Id",0);
private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"First Name","");
private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"Last Name","");
private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"E-mail","");
private final StringProperty address = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"Address","");  
private final StringProperty country = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"Country","");
```

I also created generic bean methods but it's just simple like this:

```
public StringProperty firstNamePropery(){
    return firstName;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName.get();
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName.set(firstName);
}
```

//...rest of the methods...
I tried to use this but doesn't work:

```
public IntegerProperty idProperty(){
    return id;
}
public Integer getId(){
    return id.get();
}
public void setId(){
    this.id.set(Integer.parseInt(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
}
```

Thank you for helping me on this one.

Comment: A UUID string looks like this 38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b96e4ef00d. You can't parse this string into an Integer.

Comment: Does the ID have to continue to be unique even after a JVM restart?  What about across multiple, concurrently running JVMs?  Where will the data be stored?

Comment: On this point, I'm using Preferences class in combination with JAXB because it's a really simple app, nothing complicated.I tried to use Math.random() instead of UUID, still no progress...Also, I don't need to store it as an Integer value, the string can do job but just can't get to create that number when creating a new instance of that class.

Answer (score 2):

A UUID string looks like this `38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b96e4ef00d`. You can't parse this string into an Integer.

If you want to use UUIDs as the Ids for the customers then, declare the attribute as UUID or String instead of Integer.

**EDIT I**

> Also, I don't need to store it as an Integer value, the string can do
>   job but just can't get to create that number when creating a new
>   instance of that class.

To use a `UUID` as a String:
In the `Customer` class the id attribute must be of type `String` instead of `Integer` (or `int`).
To get a new `String` representation of the `UUID` you call `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`.  The result of this call can be assigned to the customer's `id` without doing any parsing.

Also note that the signatures of the `getter` and `setter` have to change accordingly.

In the current `setId()` method you are creating a new `id`. This would override the `id` assigned when the Customer is created using the call in the constructor. If you want flexibility to assign a new id you can have the `setId` receive a new `UUID` string and assign that as a new `id` to the `Customer` object.

```
public class Customer{

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String address, String country){
       this.id.set(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    ...

    public String getId(){
       return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String newId){
       this.id = newId;
    }
}
```

**Note:** *The class name is Customer and the constructor is Person. This is wrong, both must have the same name. You must have some compiler error telling you this. I will assume the correct name of the class and constructor is Customer*

**/EDIT I**

The use case for UUID is when you need to have a unique id without checking if the id already exists with some other party (for example a database engine or a server in a network application without a central server).

If what you want to use is Integer (or Long) there is no real reason to use a Random number, you can use a sequential number for your ids.

If if is a standalone application in javafx, and you are not using different threads to create customers in parallel, then there isn't much more to worry about.

On the other side if it is a client server application. Then you have take in mind the concurrent access of clients to the server.

If you delegate the id creation as a sequence in the database then, the concurrency issue or generating duplication in the id is taken care by the database itself. This could be an autoincrement field in the same customer table (assuming you are using one), a sequence, or a table acting as a sequence. On another side, if it is a class of yours which is going to generate the ids one by one, then you will have to take care of concurrent requests. You will have to make sure that only one thread can increment the id at a time.

Regarding getters and setters, `getXxx()` returns the value of `xxx` attribute. and `setXxx(123)` would set or assign the value `123` to the attribute `xxx`;